# MSS does not take screenshot of entire screen

Tags: python-2.7, python-mss

I'm a beginner programmer and I was trying to write a program to capture screenshots. 
I am using MSS to do so.
I can capture screenshots with MSS but only a portion of my screen gets captured.
Please see code attached.

```
from mss import mss                                                     

with mss() as sct:                                                      

    for filename in sct.save(0,'test width{width} height{height}.png'): 
        print(filename)
```

Please see image attached.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ73Y.png

edit: 
    formatting errors

edit1: 
    My native resolution is 3200 x 1800. When I changed my resolution to 1920 x 1080, the library works fine.

Comment: Could you print the content of `sct.monitors`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that will be fixed quickly. You can follow the status [here](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues/57).